# Javascript getElementsByTagName not returning results

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname

I have the following XML (it's actually a gpx file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Movescount - http://www.movescount.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.cluetrust.com/XML/GPXDATA/1/0 http://www.cluetrust.com/Schemas/gpxdata10.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd" xmlns:gpxdata="http://www.cluetrust.com/XML/GPXDATA/1/0" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
  <trk>
    <name>Move</name>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="52.3535" lon="4.848642">
        <ele>12</ele>
        <time>2017-05-05T06:25:41.000Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1">
            <gpxtpx:hr>105</gpxtpx:hr>
          </gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension>
          <gpxdata:cadence>81</gpxdata:cadence>
          <gpxdata:temp>22.7000007629395</gpxdata:temp>
          <gpxdata:distance>-19.1377588523053</gpxdata:distance>
          <gpxdata:altitude>12</gpxdata:altitude>
          <gpxdata:seaLevelPressure>1024</gpxdata:seaLevelPressure>
          <gpxdata:speed>3.20000004768372</gpxdata:speed>
          <gpxdata:verticalSpeed>0</gpxdata:verticalSpeed>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

I load it via:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(xml, 'application/xml');
```

This works:

```
xml.getElementsByTagName('gpx')
>[gpx]
```

But this does not

```
xml.getElementsByTagName('gpxdata:distance')
>[]
```

Although I see that its tag name is `gpxdata:distance` in the chromewebtools.

[image: Console Output]

The [Standart](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-getelementsbytagname) says:

> The getElementsByTagName(qualifiedName) method, when invoked, must
>   return the list of elements with qualified name qualifiedName for
>   context object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gpxdata:distance` is not a tag name.

`gpxdata` is a namespace. `distance` is a tag name.

```
xml.getElementsByTagNameNS(
    "http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1",
    "distance"
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. I am new to DOM parsing and because the chrome dev tools list the tagName as seen in the pic above I could not understand why would it not select it. However, for this reason, don't you think it's a bit confusing to have the namespace and the tagName that as a tag name in the dev tools?